# Is contacting a shop without your parents knowing wrong?

Tags: halal-haram, parents

Assalamu Alaikum Warahmatullahi Wabarakatuhu,

I would like to know,

if i'm not sure if a certain food is contaminated with any other haraam food, contacting the people who owns the shop without my parents knowing. Is this wrong?

Comment: Why would you contact them if your father is asked to be in charge for you and why should this be wrong?

Comment: There is this donut shop that sells halal donuts, but also sells  other (haraam) donuts. So I'm not sure if I should contact them asking if they mix their donuts together or anything like that. Do I trust them and eat or not?

Comment: If you have not reached adulthood (not reached puberty), it is better you request your parents to investigate this as they are still incharge of your imaan. Alternately, you can either directly ask the shop keeper or if a franchisee ask the company about their products. Most companies would be gladly willing to address your concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talking with people is, in itself, not haram if the subject is not haram.

The only way I can see this as unlawful is if your parents explicitly forbade you from calling the shop, or using the phone, or another such order that conflicts with you calling the shop.

However, the fact that you are specifying "without my parents knowing" seems to indicate that they would disapprove of this. And if you know this to be true, if you **know** that, if they knew, they would disapprove, then I would advice against it.

I don't know how old you are, but parents often have good reasons to keep children from talking to strangers.

You should probably have a discussion with your parents on the subject.